# getting drop down menu Data on Flask via form is giving 400 Bad Request

Tags: flask, drop-down-menu

Here is the html and flask python code. When user select Audi from drop down menu I wanted that it give the Done as answer. I am getting 400 bad request error.

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
<form id="form1" action="/login" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select id="mySelect" name = "cars">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
</form>
<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for,request
from flask import make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    c=str((request.form['cars']))
    print(c)
    if(c == "Audi"):
           print("Done")
    return render_template('form.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of `print` in route will not affect the template. You need to pass a variable with to the template while rendering.

And as you intend to use `multipart/form-data` you might need to use `POST` method.

I am showing a scenario which you can modify as per your requirement.

`app.py` contains:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("dropdown.html")

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        car_brand = request.form.get("cars", None)
        if car_brand!=None:
            return render_template("dropdown.html", car_brand = car_brand)
    return render_template("dropdown.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`dropdown.html` contains a simple select tag with a submit button and to show the selected value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="author" content="Ahmedur Rahman Shovon">
    <title>Dropdown Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
  <form id="form1" action="/login" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select id="mySelect" name = "cars">
      <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
      <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>
  <div id="result">
    {% if car_brand is defined %}
        You have selected: {{ car_brand }}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: dropdown demo]